# How to run setup code for WAR file in External Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a spring boot application I'm building, and at the start, I need to check some system files and prepare some database pools using the information the app finds there. Normally, I'd include this in the main method of the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, however, when I deploy my app as a WAR file to an external Tomcat server, that main class doesn't seem to run. I've checked around at what you're supposed to have in that main class, and my main application class now looks like this:

```
package com.companyname.projectname;

import com.companyname.projectname.database.DatabasePoolManager;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
        DatabasePoolManager dpm = applicationContext.getBean(DatabasePoolManager.class);
        dpm.setUpPools();
        logger.error("\n\nIS ANYBODY OUT THERE?\n\n");
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        logger.error("\n\nIS ANYBODY OUT THERE? (But in the configure method)\n\n");
        return builder.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

}
```

This is different than my original setup because of the `extends` and override of `configure`.

So far, this still runs fine with my Intellij IDE, but once moved and deployed to the tomcat server, none of the log messages appear. The app still works, but is clearly missing some setup that grants it's functionality (connections to databases). How would I go about running some setup code on the application start, when I deploy this app as a WAR file?

Comment: Put that setup code in an `ApplicationRunner` or `CommandLineRunner` which will execute when the aplication started. That way it will work in either scenario. I also wonder what kind of pools you need to setup and if you actually should be doing this differently.

Comment: That was what I needed, thank you.
What I'm setting up are just Hikari database pools, during the setup I have my program go find a local TNS file and a password service, then create pools based on that. Do you have thoughts on another way to do this?

Comment: Which seems a bit hacky? How do you register those in the application context? The easiest way is to make the `setUpPools` method an init-method or call it from an application listener after startup. That way it will work in any scenario.

Comment: Ah, okay. So something like from section 2.3 of this doc:

https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

Comment: Something like that yes. Also if you know how many pools there are, why not just make them beans? Or maybe even create a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` for it so you can add bean definitions, which will be processed and manged by Spring. Again the fact that you create pools outside of Spring feels hacky.

Comment: The current idea is that it is dynamic based on a TNS file and a yaml file of passwords (the yaml file will be traded out for something more secure soon). Based on that, the pools will be created, and further down the line, I'd like to make it so new DB pools can be set up while the app is running. Can beans be added after the project is started with that `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`?

Comment: No as that wouldn't run again, but neither would your bean. Also how are those pools used? Currently they aren't spring beans, so you cannot use them for injection.

Comment: Right now, it each pool is used to grab a readied connection to a database to run a user specified query. Similar to SQL Developer, but with more fine tuning of access to a given database and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again to M. Deinum in the comments above, to run once on startup, I used this new class shown below:

```
package com.companyname.projectname;

import com.companyname.projectname.database.DatabasePoolManager;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AppStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppStartupRunner.class);

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        DatabasePoolManager dpm = applicationContext.getBean(DatabasePoolManager.class);
        dpm.setUpPools();
    }
}
```